# UIView Background color when Drawing

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Objective-C or C# .Net answers fine

I have a **UIView** in which I draw text. The background is **Black**. How do I make it **White or Clear**?

```
    public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
    {   
        using (var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {
            context.ScaleCTM(1f,-1f);
            context.SetFillColor(Settings.ColorButtonText.CGColor);
            context.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
            context.SelectFont("HelveticaNeue-Bold",20f, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
            context.ShowTextAtPoint(5,-25,_title);
        }
    }
```

[image]

**EDIT**: My Solution for a Custom Section for Monotouch.Dialog

```
public class BigBlueSectionHeaderView : UIView
{
    private readonly string _title;

    public BigBlueSectionHeaderView(string title): base(new RectangleF(0,0,320,35))
    {
        _title = title;
    }

    public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
    {   
        using (var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {
            context.SetFillColorWithColor(UIColor.White.CGColor);
            context.FillRect(new RectangleF(10, 0, 320, 35));
            context.ScaleCTM(1f,-1f);
            context.SetFillColor(Settings.ColorButtonText.CGColor);
            context.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
            context.SelectFont("HelveticaNeue-Bold",20f, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
            context.ShowTextAtPoint(5,-25,_title);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can clear the background with:

```
CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
```

Or set to white with:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```

Comment: Also make sure to set the background color of your custom view to `clear`.  It defaults to black and was thus an additional required step.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code .

```
CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```

This is implemented code.Thanks